# Showing $f\in L^2(K) \implies f\in L^1 (K)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\mathcal A, c)$ be a measure space.

For $1\le p < \infty$, let
$$L^p := \left\{ f: X\to \Bbb R \text{ (or $\mathbb C$)}\,:\, f\text{ is measurable and }\int_X \lvert f\rvert^p\, dc < \infty\right\}$$

Let $K$ be a compact set.

How to show  that $f\in L^2(K) \implies f\in L^1 (K)$?

I am finding difficulties in proving this. Is there any general technique to attack this kind of problem? Can the result be generalized?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without assumptions that put together the measure and the topology, the hypothesis of compactness of $K$ is completely irrelevant and, thus, the result does not hold.

Comment: Can you cite an example wgere it holds

Comment: An example where it holds is standard $K=X=[0,1]$. An example where it does not hold is: consider $X=\Bbb R$, $\mathcal A$ the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets, $c$ the Lebesgue measure, and the following topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R$: pick a bijection $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ and $\tau=\{f(\Omega)\,:\, \Omega\text{ open in }[0,1]\}$. $(\Bbb R,\tau)$ is a compact topological space, so consider $K=\Bbb R$. Obviously $L^p(X,\mathcal A,c)=L^p(\Bbb R)$, for which no inclusion holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assume that you have a Radon measure, namely that $m(K) < \infty$ for all compact subsets. In that way the result is then trivial. It follows by Cauchy Schwarz

$\int_{K}{|f(x) \cdot 1_{K}|dm(x)} \leq (\int_{K}{|f|^2dm(x)})^{1/2} \cdot (\int_{K}{1_{K}dm(x)})^{1/2} < M m(K)^{1/2}$ where $M=(\int_{K}{|f|^2dm(x)})^{1/2}$.

If you choose to drop the compact assumption then just assume that K has finite measure.